# jquery toggle div up and down using button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope your all well... 
Heres my jquery code at the moment- only moving the div up (not down):

```
$("#thedacbutton").click(function(){ 
    $(".thedacALLCONTENT").animate({"top":"-=558px"}, 400, 'linear');
    });
```

I want "thedacALLCONTENT" to move up when "thedacbutton" is clicked and move back to its orginal place once clicked again (down). Like a toggle... Any help greatly appreciated, thanks- Tom

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure.. what you are upto with this very less details. but you can try something like

```
var flag = true;
$("#thedacbutton").click(function(){ 
    if(flag){
     $(".thedacALLCONTENT").animate({"top":"-=558px"}, 400, 'linear');
     flag = false;
    }else{
     $(".thedacALLCONTENT").animate({"top":"+=558px"}, 400, 'linear');
     flag = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: EDIT- @dku.rajkumar - i have more than one of these sliding boxes, the var flag = true seems to be interfering with each other... Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @user1281720 you could use two different flag variables, or search for `javascript closure` because the issues is you have multiple variables named the same thing in the same scope.  Also, don't forget to mark dku's response as the answer if it solved the problem for you!

Answer (score 2):

How about using [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)?

```
$("#thedacbutton").click(function(){ 
    $(".thedacALLCONTENT").slideToggle();
});
```

Quick **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xwqQ8/)**.

Comment: unfortunately slide toggle makes the div including the button to disappear when i need it to animate up :/

Comment: hello, thanks for your time- but i cant get it to work on mine :/

Comment: Ill tell you what, ill upload it on the net and give you a link to it... Really appreciate this- you'll be able to see what im trying to do then, thanks

Comment: OK, so heres the link: http://beelinetest.site50.net/uw_virtual_tour.html# I want the 4 tabs to slide up and down when clicked- so when 'DAC' is clicked 'HOW IT WORKS' slides down and 'DAC' slides up, when 'CANTEEN' is clicked 'DAC' will slide down, 'CANTEEN' will slide up... Do you understand? Ive coloured the div so you can see whats what. Thanks again, Tom

Comment: I's start off by assigning all these elements a class that can be animated downward when any of them is clicked, except for the one being clicked. Then just animated the clicked one upward.

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply- could you post a code that makes all slide up except the one being clicked? thanks

Comment: While I don't have the time right now to try to get your code fixed, look at this example of how you can target the elements not clicked on: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ymV4u/